# PHP static function called from Javascript returning wrong value

Tags: javascript, php

I have a basic static PHP function that returns a value stored in $_SESSION.

```
static function getOption()
{
    //return correct value for title radio selection
    if($_SESSION['foo']=='one')
        return 1;
    else if($_SESSION['foo']=='two')
        return 2;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I use the value returned to set the correct value for a radio input.

```
<script>
    (function()
    {
        var opt = <?php echo Chart::getOption(); ?>;
        document.getElementsByName('foo')[opt].checked = true;
    })();
</script>
```

It works perfectly until I call my reset function, which destroys the session and starts a new one. When I call my reset function, it still echoes out the correct value in the static function. However, it returns a `"<br />"` in the script portion for some reason.

Any sort of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this actually worked at all, it certainly wouldn't work if you were calling this javascript function multiple times without a page reload.

Comment: what is inside your `reset function` ?
I think <br/> it comes from php error so instead of putting value it  puts the beginning of error line

Comment: @g33k I destroy the session in the reset function. That's all it does. But then the page refreshes which triggers the start session function at the top of the page, so I don't see why there would be an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. I was foolishly using the static function to send a $_SESSION value to another page when I could have easily just accessed the value directly from $_SESSION.

```
<script>
    (function()
    {
        var opt = <?php echo $_SESSION['option']; ?>;
        document.getElementsByName('foo')[opt].checked = true;
    })();
</script>
```

This script is set right before the end of the body tag, so DOM has already loaded and it works properly.

Answer (score -2):

Check your HMTL code and delete the `<br/>` tag.

Comment: There isn't one. That's why I'm confused.